# Rellich-Kondrachov theorem for compact manifolds without boundary.

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold **without** boundary. Is it true that the embedding
$$
W^{1,p}(M)\subset L^q(M)
$$
is compact for $1\le q < p^*$?

According to wikipedia and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1524337/is-there-a-rellich-kondrachov-theorem-for-manifolds-with-boundary), the result is true for manifold with boundary. However, I cannot find a reference for the case $M$ is without boundary.

[This paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=099D2E71C84938938D8EB6C4002207FD?doi=10.1.1.720.4957&rep=rep1&type=pdf) uses the result that I stated but doesn't give a reference so I assume that the result is standard. Could anyone please help me find a nice reference to this?

Comment: Any reference for the problem for $M $ with boundary would apply to the non-boundary case.  The result should appear in Some Nonlinear Problems in Riemannian Geometry by Aubin but I dont have a page reference available.

Comment: @TimCarson So you're saying that the "_partition of unity_" approach should work as well for $M$ without boundary? I am quite new to differential geometry so please forgive me if I ask something silly.

Comment: Yes- the boundary only adds complication that each open set of your partition either touches the boundary or doesnt. If you dont have a boundary its easier.

Comment: Section 2.11 in Aubin.